# cannot see shared folder within Notepad++ app

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

First, some environment details -
VirtualBox is being used for the VM
guest: Ubuntu 18.04
host: Windows 10

Now, the question -
There is a shared folder on the host to which the VM has access.  The shared folder is visible in the guest like so:
[image]
and:
[image]

However, when trying to open the PkgVerions.sh file in the shared folder from Notepad++ on the guest, nothing in the `/media` folder is displayed:
[image]

Is it a permissions issue?  Here is some detail about ownership of the contents of `/media`:
[image]

What can be changed so the content of `/media` is accessible from within Notepad++ on the guest?

Comment: Snaps wont read outside of your home folder.  It has been filed as a bug:  https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/snapd/+bug/1643706

Comment: have you tried opening the file with other built-in text editor like `gedit`?

Comment: `gedit` will not save files that are stored in a shared folder.